# Accessing two vectors in a struct locked by a mutex

Tags: rust

I have a struct with two vectors that is passed through a function while in a `Arc<Mutex<TwoArrays>>`.

```
pub struct TwoArrays {
    pub a: Vec<i32>,
    pub b: Vec<i32>,
}

fn add_arrays(mut foo: Arc<Mutex<TwoArrays>>) {
    let mut f = foo.lock().unwrap();
    //Loop A: compiles
    for i in 0..f.a.len() {
        for j in 0..f.b.len() {
            f.b[j] += f.a[i];
        }
    }
    //Loop B: does not compile
    for i in f.a.iter() {
        for j in 0..f.b.len() {
            f.b[j] += i;
        }
    }
}
```

When I make a loop that uses an iterator, with another loop writing inside(Loop B), the compiler complains:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `f` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
```

Loop A Compiles.

- Why is there a immutable borrow on f?
- Can I make it only borrow each array individually? That is, a mutable borrow of `f.b` and a immutable borrow of `f.a`?
- Why does this not happen when I pass `TwoArrays` directly? It only happens when I pass it in as an `Arc<Mutex<TwoArrays>>`

Comment: You can answer your first question by looking at the error.

Comment: `usize` implements `copy` so when you call `f.a.len()` you get a new usize. The borrow only lasts for the duration of the call to the length function. However, when you create the immutable iterator (you should be using `iter_mut`), you are borrowing `f` to use in the iterator. When it attempts to borrow f again to get the length of b, it finds it is already being borrowed it errors.

Comment: In loop A you just get the length value and loop with that value. But with iter() function you iterate over vector's iterator . This is the main difference

Comment: A `Vec` is not an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you unwrap the `LockResult` you get a `MutexGuard`, and **not** directly a `TwoArrays`. You can use it as if it was a `TwoArrays` because it implements `Deref` and `DerefMut`.

When you try to write 2 loops, you try to use both `deref` and `deref_mut` at once: that's impossible:

```rust
pub struct TwoArrays {
    pub a: Vec<i32>,
    pub b: Vec<i32>,
}

fn add_arrays(mut foo: Arc<Mutex<TwoArrays>>) {
    let mut f = foo.lock().unwrap();

    //Loop B: does not compile
    for i in f.a.iter() {
          //  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Implicit call to `deref` here.
        for j in 0..f.b.len() {
          //         ^~~~~~~~~~~~ Another implicit call to `deref` here.
            f.b[j] += i;
          // ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Implicit call to `deref_mut` here.
        }
    }
}
```

If you `deref_mut` once before doing the loops, everything works fine:

```rust
use std::{sync::{Arc, Mutex}, ops::DerefMut};

pub struct TwoArrays {
    pub a: Vec<i32>,
    pub b: Vec<i32>,
}

fn add_arrays(foo: &mut Arc<Mutex<TwoArrays>>) {
    let mut mutex_guard = foo.lock().unwrap();
    let real_two_arrays = mutex_guard.deref_mut();

    for i in &mut real_two_arrays.a {
        for j in &real_two_arrays.b {
            *i += *j;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access to two vector in a struct like following:

```
use std::mem;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct TwoArrays {
    pub a: Vec<i32>,
    pub b: Vec<i32>,
}

fn add_arrays(mut foo: TwoArrays) {
    let a = foo.a.clone();
    let mut b = foo.b.clone();

    for i in a.iter() {
        let mut index = 0;
        for _j in b.iter_mut() {
            let mut new_value = i.clone() + foo.b[index as usize].clone();
            mem::swap(&mut foo.b[index as usize], &mut new_value);
            index = index + 1;
        }
    }

    println!("Arrays A: {:?}", &foo.a);
    println!("Arrays A: {:?}", &foo.b);
}

fn main() {
    let a = vec![1i32, 2i32, 3i32];
    let b = vec![4i32, 5i32, 6i32];
    let two_arrays = TwoArrays { a, b };
    // let foo = Arc::new(Mutex::new(two_arrays));

    add_arrays(two_arrays);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=51fc01e27e179456ca9938e3789a54d3)

> Why is there an immutable borrow for f?

Because you tried to iterate it with `iter()` not the `iter_mut()`

> And why does this not happen when I pass TwoArrays directly? It only happens when I pass it in as an `Arc<Mutex<TwoArrays>>`

You can pass it as naked struct without the need of `Arc<Mutex<>>` with the sample code.

If you insist on using `Arc<Mutex<>>` to pass the same object around with an atomic reference you can change the function signature to the following:

```
fn add_arrays(mut foo: Arc<Mutex<TwoArrays>>)
```

And you need to `lock()` and get that reference from the `Arc` with following:

```
let foo = foo.lock().unwrap();
```

[Playground With Arc Usage](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=72f6866da162d1124931a65bae1ed78d)